# Composer install/update not working

Tags: php, linux, git, composer-php

I have a problem with Composer Package Manager. System is Ubuntu 12.04. I just can't make it work. I pulled my git project and try to run 'composer install', but it seems that nothing actually happens. I just get an information

```
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
```

then nothing actually happens. This is my log from this command run with -vvv parameter:

[here](http://pastebin.com/spSVLbhh)

Does anyone have any idea what can be wrong ? I tried to clear cache, it did not help. I am sure this repo works well as I pulled it to my Windows machine and it downloaded everything just fine. 'composer diagnose' also returned OK. 
Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Can you add composer.json and (if exists composer.lock)?

Comment: @jasir http://pastebin.com/kusb2ryS I am 100% sure it is valid so I really don't think it is about it. I don't have composer.lock since 'composer install' don't even generated it.

Comment: I have just tried, it worked. So it freezes?

Comment: @MaksymCierzniak Er, you should be running 'composer update' not install if you don't have a lock file yet.

Comment: I dont think you are right about it. I want to install(download) dependencies for first time so I should use install. Anyway I tried with update too and it does not matter. @yasir It does not freeze, it shows 'installing dependencies' and finish it so I can type a new command in terminal, so it is like it does not show any error and jest finish work but it does not do anything.

Comment: Hi, I also encountered this problem and I was wondering if you had found any solution to this problem?

Comment: @MaksymCierzniak did you get success running?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In first place You should try clearing composer cache.

```
rm -rf ~/.composer/cache
```

But more probably it's issue connected with available memory. Increasing memory_limit should help.

Comment: How can I do this in windows?

Comment: Here you can find information about default cache directory in Windows: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-cache-dir You just need to remove everything from that directory. I think you can do this by standard Windows file manager.

Comment: For people coming via google: IN case you encounter this in a VM like vagrant, try adding RAM. For Vagrant, you most likely find the RAM setting in .Vagrantfile. Try doubling it for starters.

Answer (score 12):

Try to view a verbose report:

```
composer install -vvv
```

or:

```
composer update -vvv
```

If last line shows that process is killed, you need to increase your swap memory:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=512k
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
swapon -s
```

if it continues killing the process, you need to increase 512k to 1024k or maybe 2048k

Comment: The OOM killer message comes from the kernel and is unrelated to the verbosity level.

Comment: Do not try this on vps. swapon is not executable for singular vps account root. Instead update your composer on local machine then upload the newly produced composer.lock to vps. Finally, run composer install on vps.

Comment: For me, the `-vvv` switch showed that something was indeed happening... How is it okay that an important command like this has no feedback?

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue and realised I had xdebug enabled. Disabling it fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Same here, it can be difficult to spot as the program just stops at the very start of execution.

Answer (score 4):

Try with this one and make sure that the composer.json file exist in your project directory.

```
COMPOSER=composer.json composer update
```

Comment: I have tried this, and again I tried, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

Though similar answer has already been posted above but still , if  composer install / update is not working try doing composer diagnose..
please refer..

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md

worked for me after updating my composer..
also sometimes internet might be the issue..
Happy Coding! :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable 'Listening for PHP debug connections' in your IDE.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).