# composer command does nothing

Tags: php, yii, yii2, composer-php, yii2-advanced-app

I work with yii2 in windows 10 by using xampp in my project, But composer command does **nothing** at all.

To understand more, I have to add this, that **composer** command works in **every path** exept **one** project.

my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
    "description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.6",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
        "franciscomaya/yii2-sceditor": "dev-master",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-sidenav": "*",
        "mohammad-mahdy/yii2-jdate": "*",
        "2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget" : "*",
        "2amigos/yii2-gallery-widget": "~1.0",
        "romka-chev/yii2-swiper" : "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widgets": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-grid": "@dev",
        "yiisoft/yii2-imagine": "*",
        "omnilight/yii2-shopping-cart": "*",
        "fxp/composer-asset-plugin": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"

    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800
    },
    "extra": {
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    }
}
```

For example I want to **update composer** by using `composer update` command, but in the result nothing happens.

do you know What's the problem?

[image]

[This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055425/composer-install-update-not-working) didn't help me.

please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Do you have the `composer.phar` file or have you installed composer globally?

Comment: Have you installed composer?

Comment: Yes I have `composer.phar` . I installed composer from getcomposer.org

Comment: What happen when you write only the command composer in your terminal? Is it showing the Help?

Comment: It show nothing like above picture.

Comment: I think you have to reinstall your composer. But with the Composer-Setup.exe  file from [https://getcomposer.org/download/](https://getcomposer.org/download/).

Comment: I have error in reinstall composer. Composer already installed in directory: Xampp:\htdocs\money.

Comment: I removed composer.phar, but again I got the same error.

Comment: if you have the `composer.phar` file next to `composer.json` of your project, try ask it not globally, like `php composer.phar update`. There's another issue: the PATH enviroinment variable works only when your composer path is placed before the php path. So, if you demand to use composer globally, edit the PATH variable (Control panel - System - additional params - enviroinment variables) and restart your computer.

Comment: @Nastya Kizza `composer` command works in every path except the path that I mentioned.

Comment: Just check you didn't forget a comas or some..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Please remove `composer.phar,composer2.phar and composer.bat` from your project folder and try again.

Make sure you take a backup before doing this

Answer (score 33):

What helped me was turning off debugger in PHP storm... so, check that also

Comment: xdebug session indeed at my end

Comment: Thank you very much. I have been searching for hours for a solution and that solved my issue.