# composer require is not working on git bash(Wamp)

Tags: php, composer-php

i have an issue that's occur,when i tried to use this command

```
 composer require
```

in git bash this error occurs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPjZa.jpg)

Please tell me how i install my vendor packages.

Comment: you must execute `composer install`

Comment: does composer exist in your `PATH`

Comment: composer install not working(same error occur)

Comment: composer.json availble in my path

Comment: You need to add it to your PATH variable, so you can call it from git bash. The .exe installer for composer will do it automatically. (Assuming you're on windows).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055425/composer-install-update-not-working

Answer (score 0):

**I'll just leave this here. This worked for me.**

Assuming composer is already available **globally**(if not, [install composer globally](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally) first) in your path and it is working perfectly fine in your `cmd`.
And you are only having problems on `git bash`.

open `cmd`.

```
where composer
//outputs something like: C:\xampp\php\composer.bat
//mine is located in C:\xampp\php directory
```

go to composer directory

```
cd C:\xampp\php
```

make sure `composer.phar` is inside the directory

```
ls
```

outputs something like:

```
.
..
composer.bat 
composer.phar
etc.
```

`composer.phar` is found. jackpot.

Your `cmd` is running the `composer.bat` file. `git bash` doesn't run `.bat` files so it throws an error.

Now just copy `composer.phar` into `composer` (no extension)

```
cp composer.phar composer
```

open git `git bash` and then:

```
composer --version
```

You're all set.