# 'errno=5 Input/output error' occurred while run composer update in laravel7.9.2 project

Tags: php, linux, composer-php, errno, laravel-7

I'm trying to do `composer update` in a laravel project in my local system, but caught this error:

[errno=5 input/output error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNBM3.png)

```sh
~ compoeser update

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  [ErrorException]
  hash_file(): read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=5 Input/output error
```

It's happening after installing the `php-intl` extension.

I completely reinstall php and all its extensions in my system, but the problem not solved.
also, I reinstall the composer and install another new laravel but neither solved the problem.

**OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS 64bit**

**php: 7.4.5**

**laravel: 7.9.2**

Comment: I had similar issue. turns out I was running out of disk space.

Answer (score 1):

Just run this

```
rm -rf ~/.composer/cache
```

or for more debugging info

[Composer install/update not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055425/composer-install-update-not-working)

The Verified Answer is your solution...

Answer (score 0):

In case you run that in a VM, try adding RAM. I found that my Vagrantbox defaulted to 512MB. After setting it to 2048 via .Vagrantfile it worked.